# Unable to pipe to or from spawned child process more than once

Tags: process, command, pipe, rust, borrow-checker

I want to be able to use Rust to spawn a child shell, then repeatedly pass it arbitrary commands and process their outputs. I have found plenty of examples online showing me how to pass a single command and receive its single output, but I can't seem to be able to do it repeatedly.

For instance, the following code hangs on the line after the comment. (I imagine maybe `read_to_string()` is blocking until it receives stdout from the child process, but if so I don't understand why that output isn't forthcoming..)

```
let mut child_shell = match Command::new("/bin/bash")
    .stdin(Stdio::piped())
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
{
    Err(why) => panic!("couldn't spawn child_shell: {}", Error::description(&why)),
    Ok(process) => process,
};

loop {
    {
        match child_shell.stdin.as_mut().unwrap().write("ls".as_bytes()) {
            Err(why) => panic!(
                "couldn't send command to child shell: {}",
                Error::description(&why)
            ),
            Ok(_) => println!("sent command to child shell"),
        }
    }

    {
        let mut s = String::new();
        // ↓ hangs on this line ↓
        match child_shell.stdout.as_mut().unwrap().read_to_string(&mut s) {
            Err(why) => panic!("couldn't read bash stdout: {}", Error::description(&why)),
            Ok(_) => print!("bash responded with:\n{}", s),
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner in Rust and I think the problem is my limited understanding of the borrow-checker/referencing rules, since the above runs fine (for a single iteration) if I remove the loop instruction from the code and change the references to the innards of the `std::process::Child` struct to immutable; for instance from this:

```
child_shell.stdin.as_mut().unwrap().write("ls".as_bytes())
```

to this:

```
 child_shell.stdin.unwrap().write("ls".as_bytes())
```

Obviously, repeatedly running `ls` isn't my ultimate goal, and I know that I could just write a shell script and then have Rust repeatedly run it - but (apart from the goal of just learning more about Rust!) this is something I need to be able to do, at least in principle, for a more complicated project (which I'm happy to go into if it might prove relevant to any solutions, but it's probably way, way outside the scope of this question!)

Finally, if it turns out that it isn't possible to use a child shell in this way, I'd nevertheless like to learn how to repeatedly/continuously pipe to and from a spawned process running some other arbitrary command, as I wasn't able to find any info in the Rust documentation, tutorials or on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`read_to_string`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string) is documented as

> Read all bytes until EOF in this source

Thus, it is waiting until all the input is done, which will never happen until the shell is closed. You can fix this by reading a set amount of data from the output. Here's an example where I removed all the nice error printing you had to show the core of the solution:

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::io::{BufRead, Write, BufReader};

fn main() {
    let mut child_shell = Command::new("/bin/bash")
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    let child_in = child_shell.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();
    let mut child_out = BufReader::new(child_shell.stdout.as_mut().unwrap());
    let mut line = String::new();

    loop {
        child_in.write("ls\n".as_bytes()).unwrap();
        child_out.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}
```

Here, we use the [`BufRead`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) trait to allow reading from the input until we have read one line worth. We then print that out and continue on our loop. Of course, there's more than one line of output per line of input, so this will just have more and more waiting to be read.

In your real code, you will need to have to figure out when to stop reading. This could be really easy if you have fixed-size responses, or really hard if you are trying to deal with a human-interactive program.

Be careful about using `child_shell.stdin` or `stdout` directly, without an `Option::as_ref`, `Option::as_mut` or `Option::take`. Using `stdin` or `stdout` directly will move that item out of the `Child` structure, leaving the `Child` partially valid. You would no longer be able to call `wait` or `kill` on it for example.

On an unrelated note, you don't need to call trait methods like `Error::description(&why)`. You can just say `why.description()`.

Comment: Thanks very much! All really useful advice and observations. With regard to figuring out when to stop reading from the `BufReader`, though, why is it that trying to simply call `child_out.lines().count()` or `for l in child_out.lines()` within the loop gives me a `use of moved value: child_out` error? Why can I ask the `BufReader` for one line, but not for all of them? Am I misunderstanding how iterators work here?

Comment: @John not how iterators work, but how the `self` parameter works on those methods. Check out [`count`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count) to see that it takes `self` by value, which consumes the underlying iterator, same as [`lines`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines). Calling `count` wouldn't make sense anyway, as you'd have to read *all* of the process output in order to get the count, by which time all the data would have been thrown away.